# Would this be the right place to ask for hint/guidance regarding InfoSec ctfs/challenges?

Tags: discussion, ctf

I am starting out in bug bounty training and have some need for guidance and hints towards solving some challenges and ctfs, as well as explanations on what is actually happening both in challenges I've solved and ones I haven't.

Is this the correct place to ask such questions? Does somebody know of a better community or forum to do so?

Comment: Welcome to the community. I know of couple Discord servers where such kinds of questions are welcome, but generally the CTF Discord servers are open to these kinds of general questions and I'm afraid they will be considered opinion-based and too general on this website apparently...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you care to point to the ones you know?

Comment: This was a comment and not an answer. Republic of Hackers is a good one for general needs. For specific CTF Discord servers check out CTFTime.

Comment: Most ctf's provide a decent walkthrough after the fact, so you can learn without spoilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you can show that you understand the concepts involved and can show what you have done to solve the puzzles. We do not provide tutorials or flat-out answers.